# Search meta-data (tag hierarchy/inheritance) and full-text simultaneously

Tags: org-mode, org-ql

Does anyone know of a package (or built-in functionality) that supports querying the full text of org-mode entries that takes into account the tag hierarchy and tag inheritance?

Here's an example org file:

```
#+TAGS: [ tag3 : tag2 ]
* heading1 :tag1:
content1
** heading2 :tag2:
content2
* heading3 :tag1:
content3
** heading4 :tag2: 
content4
```

I'm hoping to return heading4 and its contents when I search for "content4 :tag1:tag3:" (or a query that looks something like that).

Comment: Is this supposed to be a search in that single file? And what does the `#+TAGS:` line mean? AFAIK, it is syntactically meaningless/illegal - at the very least, I cannot find a mention of this syntax in [Setting Tags](https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-Tags.html#Setting-Tags) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: It's a tag hierarchy. See https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Hierarchy.html . And yes, I am concerned with a search in that single file.

Comment: TIL about tag hierarchies: thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`org-ql` --- Org Query Language, search command, and agenda-like view](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql)

Here is a demo of `org-ql`

***`org-ql` demo: Query by `content`-s and `tag`-s***

[image: org-ql demo: Query by content-s and tag-s]

***Demo of `org-ql` search***

[image: Demo of org-ql search]

1. Install [`org-ql` --- Org Query Language, search command, and agenda-like view](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql)
2. Copy the following snippet to `org-ql-demo.org`

```
#+TAGS: [ tag3 : tag2 ]

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
(require 'org-ql-search)
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-ql-ask-unsafe-queries nil))
#+end_src

* heading1 :tag1:

Duis fugiat nostrud voluptate ullamco dolor sit mollit amet, laborum
et id do voluptate tempor.  Magna sunt incididunt esse enim deserunt
nulla cupidatat.  Elit, esse incididunt cillum non aliqua dolor ad
sunt.
** heading2 :tag2:

Officia proident, ea laboris mollit ullamco ullamco ut.  Aliqua sit ea
velit laboris laboris enim esse lorem irure quis do magna.

* heading3 :tag1:

Ad aliquip do voluptate nulla quis tempor nisi elit, veniam,
reprehenderit cillum laborum adipiscing sunt ullamco commodo nulla
lorem aliquip.  Fugiat aute dolor sit consequat labore culpa veniam,.

** heading4 :tag2:

Elit, sed labore adipiscing sunt officia irure irure culpa esse
adipiscing.  Velit ipsum fugiat aliquip minim fugiat labore consequat
do consectetur reprehenderit aute nisi duis consequat nulla fugiat
laborum.

* COMMENT Queries

#+BEGIN: org-ql :query (and "fugiat")
| Heading  | Todo | P |
|----------+------+---|
| [[heading1][heading1]] |      |   |
| [[heading3][heading3]] |      |   |
| [[heading4][heading4]] |      |   |
| [[Queries][Queries]]  |      |   |
#+END:

#+BEGIN: org-ql :query (and "fugiat" (or (tags "tag2")))
| Heading  | Todo | P |
|----------+------+---|
| [[heading4][heading4]] |      |   |
#+END:

#+BEGIN: org-ql :query (and "fugiat" (tags "tag3"))
| Heading | Todo | P |
|---------+------+---|
#+END:

# Local Variables:
# org-ql-ask-unsafe-queries: nil
# End:
```

3. `C-x C-f org-ql-demo.org`, and do a `C-c C-c` on the `src-block` at the beginning.
4. Go to the heading named `Queries`, and put your cursor on each of the `#+BEGIN: org-ql...` lines, and do `C-c C-c`.  You can view the results, and decide for yourself what it does  (and does NOT) do.
5. If you find that a feature is lacking, open a feature request.  The author is quite active in `emacs` forums.

Comment: Hmmm. It's hard to pinpoint what's buggy about it (the hierarchy/inheritance combination functionality is very buggy), and alphapapa is not particularly focused on this project currently. I don't feel like attaching myself to a workflow that depends on a project's functionality that doesn't even work without me having to request (and may still not work after requesting). Thanks though. I followed a GitHub issue months ago where someone implemented the hierarchy support for org-ql, and it has been merged (and your "unsafe queries" code block helps), but it still doesn't really work.